# Какое веб приложение работает на DynamoDB?

Tags: база-данных, веб-служба, amazon-web-services, amazon

Здраствуйте, нужно какое-то (абсолютно любое) веб-приложение по типу wordpress'а или moodle, или любое другое, главное чтобы оно работало на DynamoDB (потому что ни мудл, ни вордпресс не работают с dynamodb).

Пожалуйста, если вы знаете такие веб-приложения, скажите название или лучше даже скиньте ссылку.

Ниже изложена полная история зачем, почему и как.

В связи с тем, что я попал в лучший колледж мира (нет), я и моя группа должны сдавать облачные технологии по стандарту Worldskills (обучаемся на системных администраторов). Есть ощущение, что в моем городе в этих самых облачных технологиях никто не разбирается и соответственно подготовить не может, поэтому приходится самим. Облачные технологии необходимо сдавать на платформе Amazon AWS *(яндекс клауд или другие облачные сервисы не подходят, так сказал менеджер компетенций Worldskills Russia)*. Также обязательно использовать DynamoDB, а не SQL или другие NoSQL СУБД. Так сказал менеджер компетенций и также про это написано в *[Задании](https://cdn.dp.worldskills.ru/esatk-prod/public_files/036caefa-7f0a-400e-96c7-ba4b450d462e-a38cb3a2d7c8fb276126d4f6e2832108.pdf)* **(страница 42-43)**.

На подготовку осталось меньше двух месяцев, поэтому нужно как можно быстрее разобраться с этим вопросом (это не мы затянули, а нас своевременно предупредили).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/dynamodb

Comment: @Денис ну хз, а есть еще что-то?